# Aumentar width de menu jquery css

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

Fala pessoal marota! :)
Grandes, baixei um menu em jquery no https://github.com/christophery/pushy/.
Achei muito legal. más não consigo de modo algum aumentar o width do menu. Ja alterei tudo do css e jquery, más quando eu aumento no css o ".pushy" que esta 200px para 300px ele sai da tela.
Pow, muito obrigado quem poder me ajudar. abs!

CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/r86a2yd1/

Comment: Você tem que aumentar o width do menu para o quanto quiser, mas deve colocar o mesmo tamanho do menu no translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que aumentar o width do menu para o quanto quiser, mas deve colocar o mesmo tamanho do menu no translate.

Onde está 200px é o tamanho do MENU, tem que ser igual.

```
.pushy-left {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
}

.pushy-open-left #container,
.pushy-open-left .push {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
}

.pushy-right {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
}

.pushy-open-right #container,
.pushy-open-right .push {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Nossa. não tinha percebido isso! funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado Gumball. Muito obrigado stackoverflow :)